# Buddypress registration page is not working

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have installed buddypress-1.8.1 plugin in my wordpress-3.7.1.I cant able to do registration.In registration page after filled up all the profile fields and if we click on complete sign up button just the registration page is getting refreshed and password field alone become vanished.It doesnt show any successfully register message.

I have read forum and tried out many solutions such as plugin conflict,theme related issues and version based issues but nothing helps me to resolve the buddypress registration page issue.

Comment: Have you checked your permalinks?

Comment: Yes i have changed the permalinks even it is not working

Comment: .htaccess rules? Access to site only for logged in users enabled?

Comment: Where i have to check Access to site only for logged in users is enabled?What i have to check in htaccess rules?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of uppercase character in my directory.The redirect url which generates after registration is in small case.

I have fixed this issue by changed my directory url to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Some theme providers (themeforest i.e supermassive theme) provide the register.php files at two places wp-content/themes/theme_name/registration and  wp-content/themes/theme_name.

please check the presence of register.php file. Correct register.php file should be in wp-content/themes/theme_name/registration and remove the register.php file from wp-content/themes/theme_name location.